# Can I delete these files? They take a lot of space

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

[image]

[image]

Can I delete these files? They take a lot of space and I found them while using `TreeSize` the thing here I don't remember downloading them!! Help
are they part of Windows? and if I delete them, does it damage my PC?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't

AppData stores the configuration and files of all your programs. If you delete it, all your programs will be reset or even unable to start.

System volume information is some backup required by the system, such as file history. You can clean it up with the Disk Cleanup tool that comes with Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** delete some files inside them!

Since your steam directory is quite big, I'm guessing that some files in your `AppData\Local` are savegame files, which can take up a lot of space over time.
You should check other folders inside one by one, see if you can safely delete anything else ... but this has to be done manually.

Files in `AppData\Roaming` are various program files which you should only delete if you don't need the program anymore. Looks like you have quite a lot of stuff installed on your system. Again, this has to be done manually and with care.

Inside the `System Volume Information` are your System Restore points. You can reduce the allocated space for system restore points - don't delete the folder or files inside yourself.

[image: System Restore]

p.s. Remember to defrag/trim your disk after extensive cleaning to make sure it keeps running nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete items inside of the AppData folder if they are no longer used, but you cannot delete the AppData folder in it's entirety safely.

My advice would be to use a program such as CCleaner, and the built-in Disk Cleanup utility.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can delete them but they will probably damage your windows installation and it stop working properly.

The safe way would be:

- for system volume information, use Disk Cleanup -> Clean up system files
- also reduce the size of your system restore allocated space and delete some older restore points
- for AppData, check what programs use a lot of space and uninstall them.

Simply deleting them will make many applications stop working and could cause different issues with Windows.